# Why is the value of the selection-screen parameter converted to upper case?

Tags: abap

I have an input field with a default value of `Test 1`:

```
PARAMETERS: gv_inp1 TYPE string DEFAULT 'Test 1' ,
            gv_inp2 TYPE string DEFAULT 'Test 2',
            gv_inp3 TYPE string DEFAULT 'Test 3'.
```

The problem is that the value is translated to upper case when writing it:

```
gv_txt1 = gv_inp1.
WRITE /: gv_txt1.
```

Result: `TEST 1`

I want to have those values without any changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to add "LOWER CASE" to your parameter declaration. For instance:

```
PARAMETERS:
    lv_para TYPE STRING LOWER CASE DEFAULT 'Test 1'.
```

Comment: you could concatenate the text variables together (concatenate with the "separated by" addition). Or you could define a single space variable and add it to your write command. Have a look at the help section at sap.com: http://help.sap.com/saphelp_46c/helpdata/en/fc/eb33f3358411d1829f0000e829fbfe/content.htm

Answer (score 1):

This is the normal behaviour for parameters unless you specify the `LOWER CASE` addition like this:

`PARAMETER: gv_inp1 TYPE string DEFAULT 'Test 1' LOWER CASE.`